# Lost Git prompt after reinstallation through Homebrew

Tags: git, prompt, bash

I used to have the brilliant Git prompt in my terminal, but after reinstalling git through Homebrew it now just shows an empty parenthesis for the branch name. The parenthesis is coloured green to show the status as before, but the branch name's missing. Do I need to change anything in my .bash_profile? This is what it currently looks like:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-05-23_at_10:37:44: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:$PATH

# Added for MongoDB
export MONGO_PATH=/usr/local/mongodb
export PATH=$PATH:$MONGO_PATH/bin

# Tell ls to be colourful
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

# Tell grep to highlight matches
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'

# Added for Git bash completion after I moved from macports to homebrew
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
 . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

PS1="Desk /W# "

# Set colour bash prompt according to git/svn branch
. ~/.git_svn_bash_prompt

# Added for Git autocomplete
source ~/bin/git-completion.bash
#PS1='[\u@\h \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
PS1="\W\$(__git_ps1) \$ "

# Homebrew
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

In response to tripleee's suggestions, here's what's in .git_svn_bash_prompt:

```
    #!/bin/bash
#
# DESCRIPTION:
#
#   Set the bash prompt according to:
#    * the branch/status of the current git repository
#    * the branch of the current subversion repository
#    * the return value of the previous command
# 
# USAGE:
#
#   1. Save this file as ~/.git_svn_bash_prompt
#   2. Add the following line to the end of your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile:
#        . ~/.git_svn_bash_prompt
#
# AUTHOR:
# 
#   Scott Woods <scott@westarete.com>
#   West Arete Computing
#
#   Based on work by halbtuerke and lakiolen.
#
#   http://gist.github.com/31967


# The various escape codes that we can use to color our prompt.
        RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
     YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
      GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
       BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
      WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
 LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
 COLOR_NONE="\[\e[0m\]"

# Detect whether the current directory is a git repository.
function is_git_repository {
  git branch > /dev/null 2>&1
}

# Detect whether the current directory is a subversion repository.
function is_svn_repository {
  test -d .svn
}

# Determine the branch/state information for this git repository.
function set_git_branch {
  # Capture the output of the "git status" command.
  git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"

  # Set color based on clean/staged/dirty.
  if [[ ${git_status} =~ "working directory clean" ]]; then
    state="${GREEN}"
  elif [[ ${git_status} =~ "Changes to be committed" ]]; then
    state="${YELLOW}"
  else
    state="${RED}"
  fi

  # Set arrow icon based on status against remote.
  remote_pattern="# Your branch is (.*) of"
  if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${remote_pattern} ]]; then
    if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == "ahead" ]]; then
      remote="↑"
    else
      remote="↓"
    fi
  else
    remote=""
  fi
  diverge_pattern="# Your branch and (.*) have diverged"
  if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${diverge_pattern} ]]; then
    remote="↕"
  fi

  # Get the name of the branch.
  branch_pattern="^# On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"    
  if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${branch_pattern} ]]; then
    branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  fi

  # Set the final branch string.
  BRANCH="${state}(${branch})${remote}${COLOR_NONE} "
}

# Determine the branch information for this subversion repository. No support
# for svn status, since that needs to hit the remote repository.
function set_svn_branch {
  # Capture the output of the "git status" command.
  svn_info="$(svn info | egrep '^URL: ' 2> /dev/null)"

  # Get the name of the branch.
  branch_pattern="^URL: .*/(branches|tags)/([^/]+)"
  trunk_pattern="^URL: .*/trunk(/.*)?$"
  if [[ ${svn_info} =~ $branch_pattern ]]; then
    branch=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  elif [[ ${svn_info} =~ $trunk_pattern ]]; then
    branch='trunk'
  fi

  # Set the final branch string.
  BRANCH="(${branch}) "
}

# Return the prompt symbol to use, colorized based on the return value of the
# previous command.
function set_prompt_symbol () {
  if test $1 -eq 0 ; then
      PROMPT_SYMBOL="\$"
  else
      PROMPT_SYMBOL="${RED}\$${COLOR_NONE}"
  fi
}

# Set the full bash prompt.
function set_bash_prompt () {
  # Set the PROMPT_SYMBOL variable. We do this first so we don't lose the 
  # return value of the last command.
  set_prompt_symbol $?

  # Set the BRANCH variable.
  if is_git_repository ; then
    set_git_branch
  elif is_svn_repository ; then
    set_svn_branch
  else
    BRANCH=''
  fi

  # Set the bash prompt variable.
  PS1="\u@\h \W ${BRANCH}${PROMPT_SYMBOL} "
}

# Tell bash to execute this function just before displaying its prompt.
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_bash_prompt
```

I've just tried commenting out this line in .bash_profile

`enter code here`PS1="\W\$(__git_ps1) \$ "

But this didn't seem to fix it. I'm opening a new terminal window after saving the change, hopefully that creates a new bash session. Apologies for my bash related ignorance!

Comment: You seem to be overriding the value of `PS1` with a string which apparently expects `__git_ps1` to return the information you say you are missing.  Did the definition of this function or script change?  Where is it defined?

Comment: On the other hand, what's in `.git_svn_bash_prompt` and are you overriding the settings it installs by changing `PS1` after invoking it?

Comment: Thanks tripleee, good point - unfortunately removing the override line doesn't restore the prompt.

Comment: So still, where is `__git_ps1` and does it do what you want?

Comment: I have it commented out at the moment - according to this page http://effectif.com/git/config it's part of the Git install, but can also be added in manually. I'll try, thanks!

Comment: Curses, prompt still empty despite adding __git_ps1 into .bash_profile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63547/discussion-between-tripleee-and-and-finally).

Comment: If you don't feel like opening up an entirely new terminal, you can just type `bash --login` at the command line and that will restart the terminal in login mode (and hence it will run the `.bash_profile` script again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case useful to anyone else, upgrading Git broke Scott Wood's nice [Git and SVN bash prompt script](https://gist.github.com/woods/31967) I was using. On reading the comments for that script, I found I just needed to change line 84 in .git_svn_bash_prompt to

```
BRANCH="${state}($(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD))${remote}${COLOR_NONE} "
```

to get the branch name back. See the comments on Scott's Gist for more details.